# How to get bold font Figure style with memoir class?

Tags: captions, memoir

I'm trying to modify the defaut figure style with the memoir class.

More precisely, I would like to have the Figure X.Y part in bold.

To get X.Y in bold isn't a problem, as the `\captionnamefont{\bfseries}` does the job.

But what about "Figure" ?

Note that adding the caption package conflicts with memoir, for those not knowing...

Comment: `\captionnamefont{\bfseries}` works for me. Could you please add an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your troubles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `\captionnamefont{\bfseries}` must work. May you are using the `subfig` package?. In any case, try with this MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

  % "This may cause unexpected or inconsistent results 
  % if you use any of memoir's captioning
  % facilities" (but work in other case?)
  %\usepackage{caption}
  %\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=bf,textfont={bf,it}}

  % Still not working captioning facilities?. 
  % Conflits with another packages?  
  %\captionnamefont{\bfseries}


  %Starting from scratch

 \makeatletter
  \renewcommand{\fnum@figure}{\textbf
  {\figurename~\thefigure}}
  \renewcommand{\fnum@table}{\textbf
  {\tablename~\thetable}}
 \makeatother    

\begin{document}
 \begin{figure}[!h]
  \centering\framebox{Image}
  \caption{The caption}
 \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I always hope the best for you and all of you in this bad time. Congratulations on the code.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using subfigures and LyX? If so, there's a behavior that IMHO is a bug. Here's an explanation.

Recent versions of LyX implement subfigures using the subfig package, and by default subfig uses the captions package. In turn, Memoir turns off its own captioning when the captions package is being used. So if you're using LyX and subfigures, all that Memoir goodness won't work.

IMHO, LyX ought to fix this by adding a checkbox on the Document Class tab of Document Settings. The checkbox should be "Use internal captioning?" A yes would use the captioning built into the selected document class; no check would load the caption package.

Then, somewhere in LyX there would be something like this pseudocode:

```
if box is checked
     \usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
else
      \usepackage{subfig}
fi
```

If the caption package is loaded, Memoir's custom captioning is deactivated. Rather than make users waste 5-8+ hours tracking down the source of the problem, the proposed fix will let the user choose which captioning to use.